# rule to run a command on newly generated files with gnumake

Tags: gnu-make

I am very new with make. I have a perl script that generates three latex files. I want to create a makefile that would execute the perl script and then run lualatex on the newly generates tex files. So far, I have the following:

```
make:
    perl diff.pl
pdf:
    make
    $(eval LIST := $(shell ls *.tex))
    lualatex $(LIST).tex
    make clean

clean:
    rm -rf *.log *.aux
```

**Output:**

```
lualatex FLAT_FLAT_AVDD.tex FLAT_FLAT_VDD.tex FLAT_FLAT_VSS.tex.tex
```

And I only get one pdf **FLAT_FLAT_AVDD.pdf**.
How can I run lualatex on all the files? 
I can just declare three variables and then run make. But, how can I automate this? Is there a loop concept in make? What is a better way to achieve this with "hard-coding" the file names?

Thanks.
EDIT:
I tried to incorporate `foreach`.

```
make:
    perl diff.pl

list: 
    $(eval LIST := $(shell ls *.tex))

pdf:
    make list
    $(foreach tex,$(LIST),$(lualatex $(tex)))
    make clean

clean:
    rm -rf *.log *.aux
```

and then I ran, `make pdf`
I got the following output in terminal.

```
dedehog01:tislam1:243 > make pdf
make list
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tislam1/Documents/THESIS/Script_v0.1/BOX_approach/Modified_Layout_mesh/IR_Report_mesh/flat_flat/make'
make[1]: `list' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tislam1/Documents/THESIS/Script_v0.1/BOX_approach/Modified_Layout_mesh/IR_Report_mesh/flat_flat/make'
make clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/tislam1/Documents/THESIS/Script_v0.1/BOX_approach/Modified_Layout_mesh/IR_Report_mesh/flat_flat/make'
rm -rf *.log *.aux
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tislam1/Documents/THESIS/Script_v0.1/BOX_approach/Modified_Layout_mesh/IR_Report_mesh/flat_flat/make'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your perl script on each make invocation, make is not really useful. A shell script could do the same. But if you really want to put all this a makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all:
    perl diff.pl && \
    for t in *.tex; do \
        lualatex $$t; \
    done

clean:
    rm -rf *.log *.aux
```

Else, you must know in advance the list of LaTeX sources. And you should probably stick with make target-prerequisites philosophy, that is, express all dependencies and the corresponding recipes:

```
LATEXSOURCES := foo.tex bar.tex ... cuz.tex
PDFS := $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf,$(LATEXSOURCES))

all: $(PDFS)

$(LATEXSOURCES): diff.pl
    perl diff.pl

$(PDFS): %.pdf: %.tex
    lualatex $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.log *.aux
```

But, as [bobbogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470195/bobbogo) noticed, with this second option, the perl script will be run as many times as there are LaTeX source files. A pattern rule solves this:

```
LATEXSOURCES := foo.tex bar.tex ... cuz.tex
PDFS := $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf,$(LATEXSOURCES))

all: $(PDFS)

$(LATEXSOURCES): %.tex: diff.pl
    @echo "Rebuilding $(LATEXSOURCES)"
    perl diff.pl

$(PDFS): %.pdf: %.tex
    lualatex $<

clean:
    rm -rf *.log *.aux
```

Now we have a true solution that:

- rebuilds the LaTeX source files only if one is missing or if the perl script changed since they were last built,
- executes the perl script only once to build all LaTeX source files,
- expresses all dependencies between the various files.

There is still a problem, however: if only one LaTeX source file is missing and the others are up-to-date, the perl script will be run, all LaTeX source files will be rebuilt and their last modification time will thus be changed. Only the missing one will be compiled but, on the next make invocation, the others will also be re-compiled, which is a waste. [bobbogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470195/bobbogo)'s proposal of using intermediate LaTeX sources solves this.

Comment: The sketch you drew will run _perl_ multiple times. It only needs to run once to create the three `.tex` files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the names of the three `.tex` files in advance, you can unconditionally run the *perl*, then update the `.tex` files only if the new ones actually differ from the old ones. *Make* will handle this fine.

```
tex := 1.tex 2.tex 3.tex
intermediates := ${tex:%.tex=%-new.tex}# 1-new.tex 2-new.tex 3-new.tex
pdfs := ${intermediates:%.tex=%.pdf}# 1-new.pdf etc.

.PHONY: perl
perl: ; perl diff.pl

${intermediates}: %-new.tex: %.tex | perl
    cmp -s $< $@ || mv $< $@

${pdfs}: %.pdf: %.tex
    lualatex $<

.PHONY: all
all: ${pdfs}
    : $@ Success
```

Let's say the perl produces `1.tex`, `2.tex` and `3.tex`

- We unconditionally run the perl producing new copies of these three files.
- Then we update `1-new.tex` from `1.tex`, but *only if the two files differ*.
- *Make* notices any files that have changed and runs *lualatex* as appropriate.

This is parallel safe (a good test of any makefile). Run with `-j3` to get 3 copies of *lualatex* running at once. You do have 4 CPUs don't you?

Comment: This will not rebuild the LaTeX sources when `diff.pl` changed but on every make invocation ;-).

Comment: Correct. It rebuilds the LaTeX sources every time, but it only rebuilds a pdf when when its source file changes. I assumed that it was much quicker to run the perl than lualatex. This scheme covers the case where a change is made to `diff.pl`. If the change produces no effect in the LaTeX, then the pdfs are already up-to-date.